# Enable scrolling in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, amslidemenu

I want to get my `UITableViewController` to scroll only when there is not enough room on the screen for all of its cells. I am using static cells that are designed to be shown in an iPhone 5, 6, and 6 plus size screen. However, when shown in the 4s screen, the bottom cells get cut off.

Ideally I would like to use `AutoLayout` to anchor the bottom of the tableview to the bottom of its superview as I have with other tableviews in my application, but Xcode doesn't allow me to add constraints to the UITableView in a `UITableViewController`. The reason I have to use the `UITableViewController` is because I am using a pod for a slide menu (https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) that subclasses `UITableViewController`.

I have tried to change the size of the `UITableView`'s frame based on the screen size because I assumed a scroller would automatically be added if the cells took up more room than the containing frame. I used the following code to do so:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - HEADER_HEIGHT)];
```

However, it had no effect on the way the table was displayed.

Does anyone know how I might be able to set the bottom of the `UITableView` dynamically and add a scroller to the cells when the screen is too small? I would also welcome any suggestions that might help avoid having to do this at all, as I would prefer not having to do anything too hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `alwaysBounceVertical` property to false so the `tableView` will only scroll when its `contentSize` is larger than the table view's `frame` which you can constrain to your view however you like.

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Comment: Adding this line did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController` height is determined by automatically calculating number of `UITableViewCell` you have presented. You can customize the cell height so that height of `UITableViewController` will automatically changed as you wished.